# What does '되먹지 못한 자' means?

Tags: translation

If i combine the individual word meaning, it doesn't feel make sense. Someone said this is a derogatory term but not commonly used these days.

Comment: 돼먹지 못한 자 and 돼먹지 않은 자 are *correct* forms. Some people make mistakes when they write 되 and 돼.

Comment: @klmo Hm, i saw it on a comic and that's how it's written, 되먹지 못한 자

Comment: Maybe the author disregards some rules of grammar. 되먹다 is "to eat again" because 되- means "back, again, on the contrary." You will see not a few Koreans do not care for the difference between 되 and 돼.

Comment: I see, no wonder it doesn't sounds right when i look at the meaning

Comment: I think correct form would be `못 되어 (처)-먹었다` or `되어 먹지 못했다` as `돼` is an abbreviated of `되어`. 이건 저는 `되돌려 먹었다`보다는 `사람이 되지 못했다`는 뜻이라고 생각해요. Also I strongly disapprove of that the phrase is not commonly used these days. It's actually one of those most frequently used swears of all time and bad language so people could be shy about this thing. xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> (1)되먹다 : 다시 먹다 eat again

되먹임 (noun) input again

내가 남긴 물을 엄마가 되먹었다. Mother drinks again water which I
did not drink completely

> (2) 막되다 be rude.

그애는 그렇게 막된 아이는 아니다. He is not rude as much as we
think.

> (3) 돼먹다 bear nobleness (cf 돼먹지 않다 It is out of standard rules)

그 애는 *돼먹지 못한* 아이다. He is a child of bad demeanors.

Comment: 돼먹다 is just a slang word for 되다; it does *not* relate to 되먹다. Maybe this 되다 means "to be grown up well" implying "to have dignity or something that a normal person has to have." 막돼 먹다 and 못돼 먹다 came from 막되다 and 못되다, respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I edited.